# Getting issues on adding the website on Porkbun domain which is hosted on Cloudflare

Tags: dns, domain-name, nameserver, cloudflare

I have made a website which is hosted on Cloudflare and I purchased a personal domain from Porkbun.

My website is successfully hosted on CloudFlare, but I want to run it on personal domain which I purchased.

I have already added the Cloudflare Nameservers in Porkbun domain settings and configured the domain on DNS Management for my website on CloudFlare.

Proofs attached:

Cloudflare nameservers:
[image: Cloudflare nameservers]

DNS Management on Cloudflare:
[image: DNS management]

DNS Config for Porkbun:
[image: DNS Config]

Cloudflare nameservers added on Porkbun:
[image: Nameservers]

Output of my website in browser:
[image: Website in browser]

Can anyone tell me why my website is not running and why is it showing this on browser, please? Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: I assume you have waited 48 hours?